# How to do Collision Detection when there are many objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using this logic to detect intersection of 2 rectangles

```js
if (this.position.x < (alien.position.x + alien.width) &&
(this.position.x + this.width) > alien.position.x &&
this.position.y < (alien.position.y + alien.height) &&
(this.position.y + this.height) > alien.position.y) {
   return true
}
else { return false }
```

It works, but the thing is, I have to iterate through all aliens to check if they are intersecting with the rectangle A and there are many aliens in the canvas and therefore performance is bad. Is there another way to improve this logic or another way to approach this?

This having issues with 9 squares (aliens) 1 bullet. Bullets are fired 2 per second and each is looping through all aliens.

Intel i5 9th Generation, GTX 1060, 16GB Ram

Comment: Do you have tens of thousands of rectangles? I wouldn't *think* that such code would result in performance problems, though ti can certainly be optimized better

Comment: Only 9 aliens rectangles, and the bullet rectangle. I can fire 2 bullets per second.

Comment: If so, no way the code in the question would result in performance issues unless you're on a toaster or something

Comment: can you create jsfeddle link? it will be easy to give solution there